# MySQL cross-table delete

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete from two MySQL tables:

```
1) table_images
2) table_images_links
```

all row entries with the same image_id and pair_id id's

```
1) table_images.image_id
2) table_images_links.pair_id
```

> And table_images_links.il.object for this id should exactly equals
>   'cat'

My query is:

```
mysql_query("
DELETE FROM table_images im, table_images_links il 
WHERE im.image_id = il.pair_id 
AND il.object = 'cat'
");
```

The problem is that nothing has happened after this query run.

My questions is: How could I trace this and make the query works according my needs.

Thank You!

Comment: Have you done proper error handling, e.g. _asked_ the database for errors it might have encountered while trying to execute your query? Have you tried that query using a frontend like phpMyAdmin, and with what results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the table where you want to delete the rows when joining tables in `DELETE` statement. In this case, use the *ALIAS* given on the table names.

```
DELETE im, il                   -- this will delete row in both tables.
FROM   table_images im, table_images_links il 
WHERE  im.image_id = il.pair_id AND 
       il.object = 'cat'
```

or

```
DELETE im, il                   -- this will delete row in both tables.
FROM   table_images im
       INNER JOIN table_images_links il 
           ON  im.image_id = il.pair_id AND 
               il.object = 'cat'
```

Comment: YES!!! DELETE im, il this is exactly how it should work!!! Thank you for this tip!!!

Comment: it will delete in both tables. if you want only 1 then specify one one table eg `DELETE im`..